# How do I skip a variable value that occurs before user input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

For my assignment I am supposed to be able to take user inputted text and reverse it. My code works for the most part, but my inverted string starts with NaN. I'm pretty sure this is because my loop does an initial run before user input is collected. I tried to fix this with an if statement:

```
if (typeof length == 'number') {
    //myLoop
}
```

This only made things worse however. I need to find a work around so that my inverted string does not start with NaN.

```
var userName = prompt("Enter your first and last name in lower case");

var length = userName.length;

var reverse;
    
        for (var i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
      
          reverse += userName[i];
      
        }
```

I have tried enclosing my loop within the if statement, and placing my if statement inside the loop; neither works.

Comment: instead of `if(typeof ..` just do `if(length){ ... }`

Comment: If that works great, could you please elaborate on how that removes the leading NaN value from my string? I'd like to have a good grasp of the logic for this.

Comment: Seems that that did not affect output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to start `reverse` with an empty string.  Secondly, you have to bear in mind that the index pointer on a string is zero-based, so the last character's position is always one less than the length of the string.

Thus,

```js
var userName = prompt("Enter your first and last name in lower case");

var len = userName.length;

var reverse = "";
    
        for (var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      
          reverse += userName[i];
      
        }
console.log(reverse);
```

Comment: Thanks ATD, its funny cause I tried adding the empty string and subtracting 1 from length independently of one another, but never at the same time. I'm gonna make it a point to make this stick. To recap, NaN popped up because length was producing a non existent index value, and notdefined pops up because the datatype was not initially defined for reverse but the datatype for the string added onto it is defined? Why does it only show NaN with my original code instead of both NaN and notdefined?

Comment: The empty string is important as you need to provide something to build on.  Without that, the variable is`undefined`.  `i` itself can be any value in the loop, but should mean something useful within the loop itself.  In your example, you are using it to point to specific characters, one by one, going backwards from the end. For the word `Hello` for example, it is 5 characters long and these are in positions: 0,1,2,3 and 4 - so you have to go from 4 to 0 not 5 to 1.  You will see a lot of code for loops like: `for (let i = 0; i < someobject.length; i++) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is incorrect. You're starting at an index equal to length, when actually the index range is 0 to length-1

Answer (score 0):

In JS, you can reverse a string in a single line of code.

```js
var userName = prompt("Enter your first and last name in lower case");

var reverse = userName.split('').reverse().join('') 
console.log(reverse);
```